# How to annotate with count in Django using datetimes() queryset function

Tags: django

In my application users visit a center to take examinations. Each day they can take one two or more examinations. I would like to filter all users that have visited the center more than 3 times (regardless of the number of examinations). I don't store visit count. I only store examination data for each user.

So, in order to get the number of times a `user` has visited the center (regardless of the number of examinations they had on each day) I do this:

```
user.examinations.all().datetimes('added', 'day').distinct().count()
```

for this model.

```
class Examination(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='examinations')
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

How can I annotate this value (number of visits to the center) to a set of filtered user, and then filter the set by it ( count > 3)

e.g.:

```
User.objects.annotate(Count('examinations__added')).distinct().filter(examinations__added__count__gt=3)
```

*(keep in mind that `added` is a `DateTimeField`)*

PS: For this project I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.8.

Comment: Could you clarify, you want to find how many users come in 3 separate days no matter how many exams did they have in each day?

Comment: yes. I need the number of visits. Not the number of examinations. Each visit may lead to more than one examination for the user. I need to retrieve all users that have paid more than 3 visits to the center.